# How to grant permission to docker user write on /var/?

Tags: docker, confluence

I'm trying to run confluence image on a docker container. This behavior is Intermittent - most of the time I can't run it, but at sometimes I can.

After downloading the image I run these commands in order put confluence online:

```
sudo chown -R daemon /data/confluence
sudo chown -R daemon /var/atlassian/application-data/confluence
docker run -v /data/your-confluence-home:/var/atlassian/application-data/confluence --name="confluence" -d -p 8090:8090 -p 8091:8091 atlassian/confluence-server
```

But then, I get this error on `docker logs confluence`

```
If you encounter issues starting up Confluence, please see the Installation guide at http://confluence.atlassian.com/display/DOC/Confluence+Installation+Guide

Server startup logs are located in /opt/atlassian/confluence/logs/catalina.out
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
Using Java: /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java
2017-05-23 15:33:41,519 INFO [main] [atlassian.confluence.bootstrap.SynchronyProxyWatchdog] A Context element for ${confluence.context.path}/synchrony-proxy is found in /opt/atlassian/confluence/conf/server.xml. No further action is required
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
23-May-2017 15:33:42.013 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8090"]
23-May-2017 15:33:42.026 INFO [main] org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool.getSharedSelector Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
23-May-2017 15:33:42.028 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load Initialization processed in 381 ms
23-May-2017 15:33:42.033 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal Starting service Tomcat-Standalone
23-May-2017 15:33:42.033 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.0.41
SLF4J: A number (1) of logging calls during the initialization phase have been intercepted and are
SLF4J: now being replayed. These are subject to the filtering rules of the underlying logging system.
SLF4J: See also http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#replay
23-May-2017 15:33:43.517 INFO [localhost-startStop-2] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log Spring WebApplicationInitializers detected on classpath: [com.atlassian.synchrony.proxy.SynchronyDispatcherServletInitializer@335dedfb]
23-May-2017 15:33:43.814 INFO [localhost-startStop-2] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log Initializing Spring FrameworkServlet 'dispatcher'
23-May-2017 15:33:43.814 INFO [localhost-startStop-2] org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.initServletBean FrameworkServlet 'dispatcher': initialization started
23-May-2017 15:33:43.819 INFO [localhost-startStop-2] org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext.prepareRefresh Refreshing WebApplicationContext for namespace 'dispatcher-servlet': startup date [Tue May 23 15:33:43 UTC 2017]; root of context hierarchy
23-May-2017 15:33:43.864 INFO [localhost-startStop-2] org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions Registering annotated classes: [class com.atlassian.synchrony.proxy.websocket.WebSocketConfig,class com.atlassian.synchrony.proxy.web.SynchronyWebMvcConfig]
2017-05-23 15:33:44,007 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] [com.atlassian.confluence.lifecycle] contextInitialized Starting Confluence 6.2.0 [build 7111 based on commit hash 583f3f4010922d699723a091097524472954c767] - synchrony version 0.3.1-release-confluence_6.1-e20fb944
23-May-2017 15:33:44.371 INFO [localhost-startStop-2] org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskScheduler.initialize Initializing ExecutorService  'defaultSockJsTaskScheduler'
23-May-2017 15:33:44.670 INFO [localhost-startStop-2] org.springframework.web.socket.server.support.WebSocketHandlerMapping.registerHandler Mapped URL path [/sockjs/v1/**] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.socket.sockjs.support.SockJsHttpRequestHandler]
23-May-2017 15:33:44.854 INFO [localhost-startStop-2] org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping.register Mapped "{[/healthcheck]}" onto public com.atlassian.synchrony.proxy.web.HealthCheckResult com.atlassian.synchrony.proxy.web.SynchronyProxyRestController.getSynchronyProxyInfo()
23-May-2017 15:33:44.855 INFO [localhost-startStop-2] org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping.register Mapped "{[/reload],methods=[PUT]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity com.atlassian.synchrony.proxy.web.SynchronyProxyRestController.reloadConfiguration(com.atlassian.synchrony.proxy.web.SynchronyProxyConfigPayload)
23-May-2017 15:33:44.873 INFO [localhost-startStop-2] org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping.registerHandler Mapped URL path [/**] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.DefaultServletHttpRequestHandler]
23-May-2017 15:33:44.939 INFO [localhost-startStop-2] org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.initControllerAdviceCache Looking for @ControllerAdvice: WebApplicationContext for namespace 'dispatcher-servlet': startup date [Tue May 23 15:33:43 UTC 2017]; root of context hierarchy
23-May-2017 15:33:45.056 INFO [localhost-startStop-2] org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.start Starting beans in phase 2147483647
23-May-2017 15:33:45.094 INFO [localhost-startStop-2] org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.initServletBean FrameworkServlet 'dispatcher': initialization completed in 1279 ms
2017-05-23 15:33:46,688 WARN [localhost-startStop-1] [com.atlassian.config.ApplicationConfig] setApplicationHome Application home does not exist. Creating directory: /var/atlassian/application-data/confluence/shared-home
2017-05-23 15:33:46,783 ERROR [localhost-startStop-1] [atlassian.config.bootstrap.DefaultAtlassianBootstrapManager] init Home is not configured properly: 
com.atlassian.config.ConfigurationException: Couldn't save confluence.cfg.xml to /var/atlassian/application-data/confluence directory.
    at com.atlassian.config.xml.AbstractDom4jXmlConfigurationPersister.saveDocument(AbstractDom4jXmlConfigurationPersister.java:86)
    at com.atlassian.config.xml.DefaultDom4jXmlConfigurationPersister.save(DefaultDom4jXmlConfigurationPersister.java:24)
    at com.atlassian.config.ApplicationConfig.save(ApplicationConfig.java:330)
    at com.atlassian.confluence.setup.DefaultBootstrapManager.populateSynchronyConfiguration(DefaultBootstrapManager.java:298)
    at com.atlassian.confluence.setup.DefaultBootstrapManager.afterConfigurationLoaded(DefaultBootstrapManager.java:509)
    at com.atlassian.config.bootstrap.DefaultAtlassianBootstrapManager.init(DefaultAtlassianBootstrapManager.java:71)
    at com.atlassian.config.util.BootstrapUtils.init(BootstrapUtils.java:36)
    at com.atlassian.confluence.setup.ConfluenceConfigurationListener.initialiseBootstrapContext(ConfluenceConfigurationListener.java:127)
    at com.atlassian.confluence.setup.ConfluenceConfigurationListener.contextInitialized(ConfluenceConfigurationListener.java:60)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4853)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5314)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1408)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1398)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Permission denied
    at java.io.UnixFileSystem.createFileExclusively(Native Method)
    at java.io.File.createTempFile(File.java:2024)
    at com.atlassian.config.xml.AbstractDom4jXmlConfigurationPersister.saveDocumentAtomically(AbstractDom4jXmlConfigurationPersister.java:92)
    at com.atlassian.config.xml.AbstractDom4jXmlConfigurationPersister.saveDocument(AbstractDom4jXmlConfigurationPersister.java:82)
    ... 17 more
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried via named volume (if using a docker version >= 1.9)?

```
$ sudo docker volume create --name confluenceVolume
$ sudo docker run -v confluenceVolume:/var/atlassian/application-data/confluence --name="confluence" -d -p 8090:8090 -p 8091:8091 atlassian/confluence-server
```

Answer (score 0):

Add ENTRYPOINT script and use it. Example - https://github.com/AfsmNGhr/dockemacs/blob/master/Dockerfile#L34. See also - http://www.johnzaccone.io/entrypoint-vs-cmd-back-to-basics/.